# Android calling AsyncTask().get() without execute()?

Tags: android-asynctask, futuretask

I'm having issues trying to understand how `AsyncTask().get()` actually works. I know it's a `synchronous` execution, However: I don't know how `execute()` and `get()` are connected.
I have this sample code from Google's docs:

```
// Async Task Class
class DownloadMusicfromInternet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Show Progress bar before downloading Music
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("Task: ", "onPreExecute()");
    }

    // Download Music File from Internet
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
           try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
               Log.d("Task: ", String.valueOf(i));
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
        return null;
    }

    // While Downloading Music File
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // Set progress percentage
        Log.d("Task: ", "onProgressUpdate()");
    }

    // Once Music File is downloaded
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Log.d("Task: ", "onPostExecute()");
    }
}
```

Now, from a `button.onClick()` I call this in 3 ways:

```
new DownloadMusicfromInternet().execute("");//works as expected, the "normal" way


//works the normal way, but it's synchronous
try {
   new DownloadMusicfromInternet().execute("").get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

//does not work
try {
  new DownloadMusicfromInternet().get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm confused as to how exactly `execute()` triggers `doInBackground()` and then immediately returns if `get()` is called, while `get()` has no effect on `doInBackground()` whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute()` schedules the internal `FutureTask` (usually on a internal `Executor`) and returns immediately.

`get()` just calls [FutureTask.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28%29) on this internal future, i.e. it waits (if necessary) for the result.

So calling `get()` without calling `execute()` first waits indefinitely, as the result will never be available.

As you mentioned, when used the normal way, `get()` is not needed at all, as the result is handled in `onPostExecute()`. I didn't even know it existed before I tried to understand your question

Comment: I was not familiar with `FutureTask` so I guess that's what sparked my confusion.